# plaudern - Konnotation

Tags: verb, connotation

Duden zufolge sind typische Verbindungen mit dem Wort "plaudern" eher positive (fröhlich, charmant, freimütig).
Trägt "plaudern" in bestimmten Fällen auch negative Konnotation?

Answer (score 6):

*Plaudern* hat nicht per se eine negative Konnotation, aber es hat eine gewisse Konnotation von Oberflächlichkeit.

Dadurch kann es dann negativ konnotiert sein, wenn es unangemessen ist, also wenn es etwa um ernste Dinge geht oder damit Zeit vergeudet wird.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt zwei zusammengesetzte Ausdrücke, die eher negativ wirken. Beide betonen den Wert des Schweigens:

- **Plaudertasche**: eine Person die zu viel (unangemessen viel) redet.
- **etwas ausplaudern**: etwas verraten, dass eigentlich geheim bleiben sollte.

Comment: + _Dampfplauderer_ - jemand, der "viel redet, wenn der Tag lang ist"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das würde ich aber nicht zwingend als negativ verstehen.

Comment: Ah, interessant! Ich kenne es nur negativ bewertet.

Comment: [Deutschlands liebster Dampfplauderer](https://www.jf-archiv.de/archiv20/202021051551.htm)

Comment: Ich finde, "Dampfplauderer" hat im verlinkten Text durchaus eine negative Bedeutung. Der Artikel bringt ja gerade eine Ambivalenz zum Ausdruck, die sich gerade auch in der Verbindung eines postiven "Deutschlands liebster" und eines negativen Attributs ("Dampfplauderer") im Titel widerspiegelt.

Answer (score 0):

Wie man am Abschnitt *Typische Verbindungen* von [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/plaudern) sieht, ist die Konnotation positiv und leicht, aber in der Nähe der Grenze zur Oberflächlichkeit.

Wenn ein Politiker im Interview, wo ihm auf den Zahn gefühlt werden soll, nur *plaudert*, dann kann das als Versuch, Ausflüchte zu machen, betrachtet werden; ein ähnlich negatives Szenario ist das Befragen eines Experten, der/die dann nur die umgangssprachliche *heiße Luft* absondert anstelle der harten Fakten, nach denen gefragt war.